# Generic service, understanding if I am in GRAPHQL context or HTTP context?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs

Is there anything that I can inject to understand which context I am in, i.e. my service has been called from a graphql request or http request.

I have a request scope service and need to return a header. The header is stored on the `REQUEST` object which can be automatically injected if its a HTTP context or otherwise it is available (as I set it up previously) on the graphql context - so hence

```
return this.request.headers["test"]
```

OR

```
return this.context.request.headers["test"]
```

But I need to understand which context I am in to return the correct object

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a helper function for retrieving the header:

```
getHeader(key: string) {
  if (this.request && this.request.headers && this.request.headers[key]) {
    return this.request.headers[key];
  } else if (this.context.request && this.context.request.headers && this.context.request.headers[key]) {
    return this.context.request.headers[key];
  } else {
    throw new BadRequestException(`Required header ${key} is missing`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work, I was just wondering if there was something from the framework that indicated to us - what context we was in.

This works though - thanks a lot